# How do i implement my sluig in my url instead of primary key in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

Apology for not defining the details properly last time. Here I have edited and post with more details. I am trying to get my slug into my url. Here's slugify from utils.py at app directory :

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

    def get_unique_slug(model_instance, slugable_field_name, slug_field_name):
        slug = slugify(getattr(model_instance, slugable_field_name))
        unique_slug = slug
        extension = 1
        ModelClass = model_instance.__class__

        while ModelClass._default_manager.filter(
            **{slug_field_name: unique_slug}
        ).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, extension)
            extension += 1

        return unique_slug
```

and here's my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from .utils import

    class Post(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=300, blank=False)
        content = models.TextField()
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.slug:
                self.slug = get_unique_slug(self, 'name', 'slug')
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("pastebin_app:detail",kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

and the urls.py codes:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .views import PostCreateView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView,SearchView

app_name = 'pastebin_app'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^search/$', views.SearchView.as_view(), name = 'search'),
    url(r'^$', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name = 'root'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\[-\w\d]+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<slug>\[-\w]+)/$', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name='update'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<slug>\[-\w]+)/$', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='delete'),
]
```

so now I am getting the NoReverseMatch error with a exception value:Exception Value:

```
Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'slug-implemention2'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>\\[-\\w\\d]+)/$']
```

'detail' is the the url i am doing the get_absolute_url to.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you can post your model and your urls.py

Comment: Can you please provide us with your code? I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Comment: make sure slug is always unique, and yeah post your urls, models and views

Comment: You can add path(<slug:slug>/), but we can only answer after seeing your code, so you can edit your question and add some code.

Comment: Pardon me for not providing enough details. I have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, I appreciate all the concern. I called sulg and pk both in my url and that solved the issue with **pk='5' not found** ,edited like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'
```

The tagging goes same for UpdateView url and DeleteView as well. 
 
and then at get_absolute_url in models.py I called both slug and pk again at views.py:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("pastebin_app:detail",kwargs={'slug':self.slug,
                                                'pk': self.pk})
```

and then one more thing i forgot that many beginners like me might do is updating the detail template where i have two buttons that work as UpdateView and DetailView. I am not sure maybe this has some shortcut

too:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'pastebin_app:update' slug=post_detail.slug pk=post_detail.pk %}" role="button">Update</a></p>
   <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'pastebin_app:delete' slug=post_detail.slug pk=post_detail.pk %}" role="button">Delete</a>
```

I forgot to call slug and pk here.